# Enrich body with data from a file

Tags: java, apache-camel

My exchange body contains a class with a string attribute with path to file with which the body need to be enriched. There another attribute to hold file after enriched. I failed to find a solution to build a dynamic route that will load a file and return result I could use in Aggregation Strategy.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the file component, you have to specify a path to a directory which can't be dynamic. You can only specify patterns on files in the directory.

Extract from the camel-file [doc](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html):

> Camel **supports only endpoints configured with a starting directory**. So
> the directoryName must be a directory. If you want to consume a single
> file only, you can use the fileName option, e.g. by setting
> fileName=thefilename. Also, the starting **directory must not contain
> dynamic expressions** with ${ } placeholders. Again use the fileName
> option to specify the dynamic part of the filename

Could you give us more info on what your are trying to achieve, so that we can give you workarounds ?